# Prove that for $n \ge 2$ the follow inequality holds $\frac {4^n}{n+1} \lt \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, factorial

As already shown above I need to prove that $$\frac {4^n}{n+1} \lt \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\qquad \forall n \ge 2.$$

What I've come up with is the following:

$\underline{n=2:}\qquad$ $$\frac {16}{3} \lt 6$$

$\underline{n=k:}\qquad $$$\frac {4^k}{k+1} \lt \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}  $$

$\underline{n+1}:$ $$\frac {4^{k+1}}{k+2} \lt \frac{(2(k+1))!}{((k+1)!)^2} $$
 $$\frac{4^k \cdot 4}{k+2} \lt \frac {(2k+2)!}{(k!)^2\cdot(k+1)\cdot(k+1)}$$
$$\frac{4^k \cdot 4}{k+2} \lt  \frac{(k+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (k + (k-1))\cdot{2k} \cdot (2k+1)\cdot(2k+2)}{(k!)^\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}2\cdot(k+1)\cdot(k+1)}$$
$$\frac{4^k \cdot 4}{k+2} \lt  2 \cdot\frac{\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(k+1)}\cdot \ldots \cdot (k + (k-1))\cdot{2k} \cdot (2k+1)\cdot\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(k+1)}}{(k!)\cdot\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(k+1)}\cdot\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{(k+1)}}$$
$$\frac{4^k \cdot 4}{k+2} \lt  2 \cdot\frac{{(k+2)}\cdot \ldots \cdot (k + (k-1))\cdot{2k} \cdot (2k+1)}{(k!)}$$

From here on I'm stuck. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: In the 6th line of equations, you cancelled off the $k!$ in $\frac{(2k)!}{({k!})^2}$.  You cannot do that because $(2k)!$ does not equal $2(k!)$

Comment: @HarryAlli Did I make a good edit for my mistake?

Comment: Yes, that is looking correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k+1$ it is equivalent to

$$
\frac{4^k}{k+1}<\frac{(2k+1)(k+2)(2k)!}{2(k+1)^2(k!)^2}$$

It is enough to prove that

$$\frac{(2k+1)(k+2)}{2(k+1)^2}>1$$

Notice that the above fraction is monotonically decreasing and its limit at $k\to\infty$ is $1$, therefore it is always greater than $1$.

And also, you have a mistake, as Harry noticed, $(2k)!\neq2k!$.

## Edit

I have no idea what is Jaroslaw talking about. There is step-by-step solution. Suppose it is true for $k$. Then it is true for $k+1$ if and only if

$$\frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}<\frac{(2k+2)!}{\left((k+1)!\right)^2}\\\frac{4^k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}<\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!}{(k+1)^2(k!)^2}\\\frac{4^k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}<\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\cdot\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$

It is enough to prove that:

$$\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}<\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$

It is equivalent to

$$\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}>\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}\\\frac{2(k+1)(2k+1)(k+2)}{4(k+1)(k+1)^2}>1\\\frac{(2k+1)(k+2)}{2(k+1)^2}>1$$

Comment: My apologies for that. I'll edit that

Comment: Your inequality, that You say is equivalent, actually isn't equivalent. On the left side of equivalent inequality there should be $\frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}$ and on the right side $\frac{(2k+1)(k+\color{red}{1})(2k)!}{2(k+1)^2(k!)^2}$

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak. Actually the inequalities **ARE** equivalent, because we have that $k\ge3$. There is logical equivalency between original inequality for $k+1$ and my inequality. Why downvote? Do you want a proof or what? Please reconsider your vote. Thanks.

Comment: For the left side - I really don't know how inequality $a<b$ could be equivalent to $c<b$, especially when $a<c$.
For the right side - obviously your version is an one way implication. Can you proove the other way implication? And also it doesn't give us the expected right side.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak. I don't understand what do you mean. Please take a look at my answer again, I added an edit. I don't see what is incorrect in my implications. And, please reconsider your vote. Thanks.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Now your reasoning is clear for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{\frac{4^{n+1}}{n+2}}{\frac{4^n}{n+1}}=4\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$ and that $$\frac{\frac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!^2}}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{n!^2}{(n+1)!^2}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=2\frac{2n+1}{n+1}. $$So, when is it true that$$4\frac{n+1}{n+2}\leqslant2\frac{2n+1}{n+1}?$$ Well, the previous inequaliy is equivalent to $2(n+1)^2\leqslant(2n+1)(n+2)=2n^2+5n+2$, which clearly holds always. So, since you proved that $\frac{4^2}{2+1}<\frac{(2\times2)!}{2!^2}$, the inequality that you want to prove is true whenever $n\geqslant2$.

Comment: Is this way of proving considered as an induction proof or a heuristics proof? Because you used the $P(n+1)/ P(n)$-technique with P is the statement above.

Comment: @AnonymousI What I provided is an almost complete proof by induction. Let $a_n=\frac{4^n}{n+1}$ and let $b_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$. In order to complete the proof from what I did, the only step missing is to observe that, if $a_n<b_n$, then $a_{n+1}=a_n\times\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<b_n\times\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=b_{n+1}$.

Comment: I'm just used to the conventional way of using induction without any tricks. I need a lot more of exercises to get the hang of induction. I'll try some math olympiads questions.

Comment: @AnonymousI This is *not* a trick! It is the standard way of proving statements of the type $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):a_n<b_n$ (or $a_n\leqslant b_n$) when the $a_n$'s and the $b_n$'s are defined in a multiplicative way.

Comment: Oké, I just need more exercises to work on. My apologies for the previous remark.

Comment: Where does the last 2 between** come from in $2(n+1)^2\leqslant*2*(2n+1)(n+2)=4n^2+12n+4$

Comment: @AnonymousI It shouldn't be there. My mistake. I've edited my answer. Please tell me if all is well now.

Comment: I'd think that the 4 is divided by the 2 in $4\frac{n+1}{n+2}\leqslant2\frac{2n+1}{n+1}$ and that's it

Comment: Yep everything is ok.

Comment: @AnonymousI That's what I did. And then I multiplied both sides by $(n+1)(n+2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and patience

Comment: I've another question: If you say that P(n+1)/ P(n) is that similar to this. Or is it completely false.

Comment: @AnonymousI I have no idea about what you mean by this.

Comment: Your approach is just not directly similar to the basic induction proofs for me. I just have a hard time with writing it down formally.

Comment: I think I now see the missing link which is the induction hypothesis for $a_n$ and $b_n$ in $a_{n+1} =a_n \times \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \lt b_n \times \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}=b_{n+1}$ without those in the fractions.

Comment: @AnonymousI Then re-write my approach in a way which *is* similar to the basic induction proofs that you are aware of. Besides, why are you even interested in my method? You marked another answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I think I see it now. I think I have defined asking stupid questions on a whole new way. I can't stress enough how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to good sites or good books on how to solve inequalities?

Comment: @AnonymousI No. I am not strong on inequalities.

Comment: Oh, ok. Have a good day, sir.

Answer (score 1):

As your first steps of mathematical induction are right, I'll just perform a proof of inductive thesis for $n=k+1$.

First notice, that for $k>1$
$$\frac{4(k+1)}{(k+2)} < \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$
proof:
$$(k-1)k(k+1)^2(k+2)>0\\
\frac{k(k-1)}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}>0\\
\frac{4k^2-4k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}>0\\
\frac{-4k^2+4k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}<0\\
\frac{4(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)-(4k^3+16k^2+8k+4)}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}<0\\
\frac{4(k+1)^3}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}<\frac{4k^3+16k^2+8k+4}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}\\
\frac{4(k+1)^2}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}<\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)(k+2)}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}\\
\frac{4(k+1)}{(k+2)}<\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$

Thus, since $\frac{4(k+1)}{(k+2)}$ and $\frac{4^k}{k+1}$ are both positive, we have:
$$\frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}=\frac{4(k+1)}{(k+2)}\frac{4^k}{k+1} < \frac{4(k+1)}{(k+2)}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}<\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} = \frac{(2k+2)!}{(((k+1)!)^2}$$

Comment: Why can you bring that other inequality to mine equality?

Comment: Why not? As you track the last chain of inequalities you'l see, that at each step I swap one factor with the bigger one (first $\frac{4^k}{k+1}$ with $\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$ - your inductive assumption, and then  $\frac{4(k+1)}{k+2}$ with $\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$ - my inequality, that I've prooved for $k>1$). As a result I've obtained your inductive thesis. Are there some forbidden steps that I've missed?

Comment: Yes I've noticed that but how do you come up to prove that particular statement and use it in such a manner to prove my inequality?

Comment: I didn't even know you could prove this like that. I just thought of induction and nothing else.

Comment: Notice, that both sides of my inequality are factors, that are contained in your inductive thesis, but are missing in inductive assumption. I've checked, if they satisfy my inequality (track my proof from the end to the begining) and then prooved it. 
In my answer there is not a full inductive proof of your inequality - I've just prooved that the thesis is right if the assumption is true.