# Prove the inequality following by induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction, factorial

So, I was stuck with this induction problem i.e

Show that P(n) : $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} > \frac{4^n}{n+1}$ for all integers n > 1

I tried doing the following and reached the answer but do not know if it is correct. Would appreciate input.

Basic Step: P(2) is true.

Inductive Step: For some k, P(k) is true.......

$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} > \frac{4^n}{n+1}$

P{k+1): is as follows:

We can show that
$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} > \frac{4^n}{n+1} > \frac{4^n}{n+2}$

and

$\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2} =\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}.\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} > \frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}.\frac{4^k}{(k+2)}$

Now, for all integers $k > 0, 2k + 1 > 2k  and  2k + 2 > 2k.$ Hence, we can replace this in the above formula

$\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2}  > \frac{(2k)(2k)4^k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}$

or

$\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2}  > \frac{k^2 4.4^k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}$

Now, since $k + 1 > k$, we have

$\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2} < 1$

Hence, we replace and complete the proof:

$\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2}  > \frac{4.4^k}{k+2}$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You conclusion that $\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2} \gt 1$ is not true, e.g., for $k = 1$, we have $\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4} \lt 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that for $n \ge 2$ the follow inequality holds $\frac {4^n}{n+1} \lt \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437448/prove-that-for-n-ge-2-the-follow-inequality-holds-frac-4nn1-lt-frac) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B(2n)!%7D%7B(n!)%5E2%7D%5Cgt%5Cfrac%7B4%5En%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cgt%201%24&p=1). There's also quite a few other duplicates, in the search result list and/or linked to various questions, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Prove by induction: $\frac{2^{2n}}{n+1}<\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2},n>1$](/q/1500512), [Problem proving inequality $\frac{4^n}{n+1}\leq \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$](/q/2008867), [Prove that $\frac {(2n)!} {(n!)^2} > \frac{4^n}{n + 1}$](/q/1537358), etc.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yeah a small typo, I meant the other way around i.e $\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2}<1$

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, note that with this correction, your final line of $\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2}\gt\frac{4.4^k}{k+2}$ doesn't necessarily follow from your previous line of $\frac{(2(k+1)!}{((k+1)!)^2}\gt\frac{k^2 4.4^k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yeah my fault. I see it. Could you help me with the complete proof? I saw the other answers, but they are mostly the other way round, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Note many problem solution approaches are not successful. The inequality issue encountered with your particular approach means it doesn't work.